# Exist Validation doesn't work in Yii

Tags: php, validation, yii

I have a problem with exist validation in Yii. When I run my code, there is not firing exist validation. I don't know what the problem.

Here is Rule in User Model:

```
public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('id_cabang, username, password, nama, level', 'required', 'on'=>'create'),
            array('username, nama, level', 'required', 'on'=>'update'),
            array('id_cabang, nohp', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('username', 'length', 'max'=>20),
            array('password', 'length', 'max'=>20),
            array('nama', 'length', 'max'=>100),
            array('jabatan', 'length', 'max'=>100),
            array('nohp', 'length', 'max'=>14),
            array('level', 'length', 'max'=>10),
            array('username', 'exist', 
                'attributeName'=>'username', 
                'className'=>'User', 
                'caseSensitive'=>true, 
                'on'=>'create'
            ),
            array('username', 'exist', 
                'attributeName'=>'username', 
                'className'=>'User', 
                'caseSensitive'=>true, 
                'criteria'=>array('condition'=>'username<>:u', 'params'=>array(':u'=>$this->current_username)),
                'on'=>'update'
            ),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('id_cabang, username, nama, nohp, jabatan, level', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }
```

Here is my actionCreate in User Controller:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new User;
        $model->scenario = 'create';
        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['User']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['User'];
            $model->id_cabang = 1;
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('index'));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
```

Please help me..

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

To answer this we need to know what are you trying to accomplish. Based on your exist validator parameters for update i am guessing that you try to check or uniqueness.

If you need to check if username is unique through all records, then there is a validator for it: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/CUniqueValidator .

Otherwise you need to specify what do you want, and check this reference:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/reference-model-rules-validation/

Comment: Yes, you right. I want check username to database when adding new user. I will try to use unique validator. Thank you.

Comment: @RizaldiMaulidia If this answer, or any other, was helpful or solved your problem, you can accept it.

Comment: it's work! thank you. I tried using unique validation.

Answer (score 0):

if you want some columns is required, you should write your code like

```
public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array(array('id_cabang', 'username', 'password', 'nama','level'), 'required','on'=>'create'),
        );
    }
```